# Loading Data in Power BI ( txt file | file size is greater than 10GB )

Tags: database, powerbi, dataset

I have a dataset in txt ( size is greater than 10gb ). I wanted to load this dataset in power bi. while i was trying to load the dataset through bi service it is not letting me upload. Is there an alternative? The file is too large to convert the txt to csv file and then load in the service.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The dataset sizes allowed for Power BI are:

Pro - 1GB

Premium - +10GB (For premium you will have to set the [Large Model Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-large-models))

For a data size of 10GB, it is recommended that you use a database to store the data in, and connect it to Power BI using direct query mode. If you have the option of reducing the dataset, down by some sort of aggregation to a suitable file size, try that.